# Firestore transaction failing inside forEach loop

Tags: firebase, transactions, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to update several Firestore documents, based on the result of a third-party service inside a transaction. Problem is, I am getting the following error:

> Error: Cannot modify a WriteBatch that has been committed.

Here is my code:

```
export default async function debitDueTransactions(context: any) {
  const now = new Date().getTime();
  return db.runTransaction(async (transaction: FirebaseFirestore.Transaction) => {
    const chargesToCaptureRef = db.collection(`charges_to_capture`)
      .where('dateToCapture', '>=', now)
      .where('dateToCapture', '<=', (now + 86400000))
      .where('captureResult', '==', null);
    return transaction.get(chargesToCaptureRef).then((chargeToCaptureQuerySnap: FirebaseFirestore.QuerySnapshot) => {
      chargeToCaptureQuerySnap.forEach(async (doc: FirebaseFirestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot) => {
        const chargeToCapture = <ChargeToCapture>doc.data();
        chargeToCapture.id = doc.id;
        let errorKey = null;
        // Calling third party service here, waiting response
        const captureResult = await captureCharge(chargeToCapture.chargeId).catch((error: any) => {
          errorKey = error.code ? error.code : 'unknown_error';
        });
        transaction.update(doc.ref, { captureResult: captureResult, errorKey: errorKey });
      });
      return new Promise((resolve) => { resolve(); });
    })
  });
}
```

Can't get what I am doing wrong, any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from the API documentation, [transaction.get()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Transaction#get) only accepts a DocumentReference type object.  You're passing it a Query object.  A Firestore transaction isn't capable of transacting on a Query.  If you want to transact on all the documents returned from a Query, you should perform the query before the transaction, then use transaction.get() on each DocumentReference individually.

Comment: Trying to apply what you suggested, will come back to you as soon as I get this to work. Thanks